# Large Angular material popover should make the parent content scrollable

Tags: angular, angular-material, popover, angular-cdk, scrollable

I have a popover in my project with some checkboxes listed below the other.

Right now everything is working fine, but when the screen's resolution is kinda small, the content gets chopped on the bottom and the parent container isn't scrollable, this only happens with CdkOverlay since it doesn't seem to affect the parent content when the popover is displayed, you can see a working example on this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-popover-aq3ft9)

I can't share my main code but this is what I've tried on the stackblitz and it's pretty similar to my project:

```
 <div
  cdkScrollable
  style="height: 100px; overflow-y: auto; border: 1px solid green">
  <button
    (click)="isOpen = !isOpen"
    cdkOverlayOrigin
    #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin">Show</button>
  <ng-template
    cdkConnectedOverlay
    [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
    [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen">
    Popover content 
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

As you can see on the link the parent won't get a scroll when the popover is open, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cdk-overlay is attached outside the app

if the only you want is change the "parent" you can do it in the (attach) event

```
<!--see the template reference variable "anchor" 
    and the style="position:relative"-->
<div #anchor
    style="position:relative;
    height: 100px; 
    overflow-y: auto; 
    border: 1px solid green ">
  <button (click)="isOpen = !isOpen" cdkOverlayOrigin #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin">
    Show
  </button>

  <!--in attach event you pass the "anchor"-->
  <ng-template #template
    cdkConnectedOverlay
    (attach)="changeParent(anchor)"
    ...
  >
   ...
  </ng-template>
```

The changeParent it's simply:

```
  //in constructor inject the Overlay service
  constructor(private overlay: Overlay) { }

  changeParent(el:any)
  {
    //get the "cdk-panel
    const container=(this.overlay as any)
                        ._overlayContainer.getContainerElement()

    //it's necessary change the position to "absolute"
    container.style.position='absolute'

    //and take account the position of the div
    const rect=el.getBoundingClientRect()
    container.style['margin-top']=-rect.top+'px'
    container.style['margin-left']=-rect.left+'px'


    //change the parent using appendChild
    el.appendChild(container);
  }
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fxnpkk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Yes! this is exactly what I was needing, although it requires putting the relative position on the parent component, it's not a big deal, Thanks

Comment: @DJG22, I'm afraid that are neccesary some ajust. If the div is in the "top" work, but if not, we need adjust the position. I work on this and update my answer when get it

Comment: @DJG22, just do it :). NOTE: You can use `el.style.position="relative"` if you don't  write in the .html or use .css

Comment: Its working fine with the original solution, the original HTML isn't similar to the stackblitz, that was just a sample since I cannot share the original code

Comment: @DJG22, in the stackblitz I updated it to add the "position.relative" and to take account the position. My comments are about it.

Comment: sorry about the bounty, I just awarded the points to you, thanks for this, you helped me a lot!